# How to reduce swipe sensitivity in the carousel view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a carousel view in Xamarin forms project. Inside I use Collection view. When I scrolling collection I can by accident swiping tab. I think that a good solution would be to reduce the sensitivity of the swipe in the carousel but I donʼt know how I can do it. I have this problem on android.

I tried to fix it with the standard properties and events. But I failed.

Comment: Do you scroll vertically or horizontally? If you use vertical scrolling. I found a similar issue in the Xamarin.Forms Github page: [Horizontal swipe too sensitive](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/issues/15), please follow the progress about it.

Comment: Carousel have horizontal scroll, collection inside have vertical

Comment: This is a known problem. You can also refer to another link on GitHub: [SwipeView is too sensitive - opens when scrolling](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12518).